# How to use the eval method with global parameters in python

Tags: python, lambda, eval

I want to assign a dozen of properties to a lxml node. The lambda is used to simplify the typing. The comment assignment operations are OK but use the lambda sa will throw exception. Does anyboy know is it possible to use lambda in this case? 
Thank in advanced!

```
sa = set_attr = lambda n, v: eval("etp.xpath(u'/Recipe_Definition/%s')[0].text = u'%s'" % (n, v), {u'etp':etp})
#etp.xpath(u'/Recipe_Definition/Author')[0].text = rc.author
#etp.xpath(u'/Recipe_Definition/Comment')[0].text = rc.comment
sa(u'Author', rc.author)
sa(u'Comment', rc.comment)
```

The exception will be:

```
  sa = set_attr = lambda n, v: eval("etp.xpath(u'/Recipe_Definition/%s')[0].text = u'%s'" % (n, v), {u'etp':etp})
File "<string>", line 1
  etp.xpath(u'/Recipe_Definition/Author')[0].text = u'admin'
```

Comment: Why use `eval()` **at all** here? It is not needed.

Comment: Just want to reduce typing codes. It's a little bit overkilled. :)

Comment: unicode(v) is not working.

Comment: But `u'%s' % v` *is*? I dropped it from the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You do **not** need to use `eval()` here. At all. Don't use `eval()` to interpolate string values into other string values. Moreover, assignment in a `lambda` is not allowed (assignment is a statement, and a `lambda` only supports expressions).

The following `lambda` does the *same thing*:

```
lambda n, v: setattr(etp.xpath(u'/Recipe_Definition/' + n)[0], 'text', v)
```

and uses `etp` as a global. You can also pass in `etp` as an argument if `etp` is not a global of the module you defined the `lambda` in:

```
lambda etp, n, v: setattr(etp.xpath(u'/Recipe_Definition/' + n)[0], 'text', v)
```

Comment: etp is not a global variable, it's define in a local method. The reason it add as the parameter of eval is I guess may be the eval method can't catch the lxml node

Comment: "lambda etp, n, v: etp.xpath(u'/Recipe_Definition/' + n)[0].text = v" This syntax is wrong. The compiler will raise error about you can't assign value to lambda expression

Comment: That is the reason why I try to use eval by pass this case.

Comment: @Erxin: ah, yes, assignment.

Comment: @Erxin: `eval()` still only supports valid Python, you cannot work around syntax errors by using that route.. :-)

Comment: Yes, wait for and see if there is any other solution to this case. First of all I have to get back home and check the post later. It will dark outside.